# Make a struct or class implicitly convertible to String

Tags: swift, swift2

Bonjour :)

I am trying to build a custom type (struct or class, any will fit) whose value could be implicitly converted to `String` when I need it to.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
public struct IKString {
    private var internalValue: String

    public init(_ value: String) {
        internalValue = value
    }
}

...

let test = IKString("Hello, world!")
myUILabel.text = test // This fails but I'm looking for a way to make it compile
```

Is that possible in Swift?

Comment: Swift intentionally avoids implicit casting (conversions). There is a reason for it. If you want to write good code, don't try to introduce implicit conversions to Swift.

Comment: check http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/CustomStringConvertible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class C: CustomStringConvertible {
    let property1: Int; 
    init(i: Int) {
        property1 = i
    }

    var property2: ()->() = { print("some computed property") }
    var description: String {
        return "instance of this class C has two properties: property1: \(property1) and property2: \(property2) whith type \(property2.dynamicType)"
    }
}
let c  = C(i: 100)
let s: String = c.description
print(s) // instance of this class C has two properties: property1: 100 and property2: (Function) whith type () -> ()
```

see that

```
print(c)
```

gives you the same result!

and

```
var text: String = ""
print(c, toStream: &text)
print(text)
```

sets the text to the same value. By the way

```
print("\(c.property2), \(c.property2())")
// prints two lines
/*
some computed property
(Function), ()
*/
```

UPDATE 
what about extension String:IKString { ... } ??

```
struct Localisation {}
protocol IKString {
    mutating func foo()
    init(s: String, l: Localisation)
}

extension String: IKString {
    init(s: String, l: Localisation) {
        // some code
        self = s
        foo()
    }
    mutating func foo() {
        self = self.uppercaseString
    } 
}
let s2 = String(s: "blabla",l: Localisation())
print(s2) // BLABLA
```

Comment: Thanks but I am sorry, although this code works indeed, it doesn't exactly do what I am asking for. You are instantiating your `String` like this: `let s: String = c.description`. I want `c` to be implicitly convertible to `String` without any additional property or method, like this: `let s: String = c`. But as @Sulthan mentioned, this might simply not be possible in Swift, nor desirable...

Comment: @Romain the description property is a requirement of CustomStringConvertible protocol. `let s: String = c` means, that c is of String.Type. if c is something what adopts CustomStringConvertible, than `let s: String = "\(c)"` should work too. using c.description is very clear and intuitive, why is it 'not acceptable' for you? Am i missing something?

Comment: Yes I understand what `CustomStringConvertible` is for, and in most cases it is perfectly fine. Here however, I'm developing a framework for other developers, and I would like to provide them with a simple, string-convertible type, to deal with localizable strings in a multi-bundle project. Ideally, my `IKString` type would be initialized with the localization key, and be automatically converted to the expected localized `String` when needed. `IKString` would take care of bundle and table name for the developers, transparently, without things like `IKString("blabla").description`.

Comment: @Romain what about let s = String(c)   ... it works as expected, now s is String.Type (if c conforms to CustomStringConverible). Such API would be very clear and easy understandable for everybody working in Swift. Other solution is to define your functionality as extension String { .... all you 'IKString functionality' ... }

Comment: You're right, I will explore the `String` `extension` solution

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `CustomStringConvertible` conformance solution (which I believe is preferable, +1!), you can define your own custom operator to do the conversion job for you (i.e., accessing the `internalValue` string property). In this example, I'll make use of a prefix operator to to conversion prior to normal `String` to `String` assignment via operator `=`. As an alternative, you could create your own infix assignment operator.

```
prefix operator <- {}

prefix func <- (rhs: IKString) -> String {
    return rhs.getInternalValue()
}

public struct IKString {
    private var internalValue: String

    public init(_ value: String) {
        internalValue = value
    }

    func getInternalValue() -> String {
        return internalValue
    }
}

let myIKString = IKString("Foo")
let myString : String

myString = <-myIKString
print(myString) // Foo
```

Comment: i think, the best what could be done 'standard way' is to make your type to conform to http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/CustomStringConvertible

Comment: @user3441734 that's really nice and the way to go here! Didn't know about that, thanks :) anyway, I'm on a cell, so you should provably add an answer using that method, if you have the time!

Comment: I forgot to mention that my `struct` already conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, but from my testing, it doesn't help for what I'm looking for. `CustomStringConvertible` only allows my type to be initialized with a  `String`, but not the other way round (initialize a `String` from my own type).

Comment: @Romain no, that protocol is exactly, what you want, to customize textual representation of your object. it has nothing with initialization.

Comment: Thanks @user3441734, then I would love to have some sample code, because based on my testing, I can surely do things like `let test: IKString = "Hello, world!"`, but not the other way round, like: `myUILabel.text = test` (where `test` is of type `IKString`).

Comment: @dfri +1 for the idea of using a custom operator to "bridge" `IKString` to `String`. I understand there might not be any other, more "transparent" way of doing this anyway.